# After switching to Android App Bundle build format, The Unity Plugin for Branch.IO fails to initalize

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, branch.io

After switching our Unity game to Android App Bundle build format,the Branch.IO plugin no longer will initialize (or at least the callback never happens from `Branch.initSession`) It was working before with apk builds.

I'm using Unity 2019.2.0f1 and version 0.5.13 of the Branch Unity Wrapper

Is this a known issue with Branch? Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

**Please make sure that you are not missing any of the below points:**

- Configure Branch with the prefab (click on "Update iOS Wrapper" & "Update Android Manifest"). Match your Branch prefab inspector as mentioned [here](https://docs.branch.io/apps/unity/#configure-app).
- Make sure to initialise Branch in MonoBehavior file in Start() as mentioned [here](https://docs.branch.io/apps/unity/#initialize-branch).
- Make sure that the link you are clicking on have the same Branch key as the one you put in your AndroidManifest.xml (you can append ?debug=1 to the link to see more details)
  4.Are you using third party plugin? If yes then please resolve it using this documentation:
  https://github.com/BranchMetrics/unity-branch-deep-linking-attribution/tree/master/ThirdPartySolutions

Our recommended setup is outlined here, please follow it as closely as possible to avoid confusion:
https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/unity/#integrate-branch

Here is our "gold standard" example app of a working Branch application with loads of features implemented:
https://github.com/BranchMetrics/unity-branch-deep-linking/tree/master/BranchUnityTestBed

In case you are still facing the issue then feel free to write to support@branch.io.

Comment: this might also help:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-app-bundle-google-play-app-signing-what-option-do-we-use-with-unity.604723/

Comment: I've checked those points and I was using the setup documentation anyway. I've gone ahead and tried doing a build with the BranchUnityTestBed project as an aab unity export and it doesn't seem to work for me. Do you know if aab format unity builds work with Branch.io?